# SQL large table VS. multiple smaller tables

Tags: sql

I have the option to use a single table that will expand upwards of 1,000,000 records per year.

With that said, I could use a foreign key to break up this table into muitiple smaller tables, which will reduce this expansion to each smaller table of 100,000 records per year.

Lets say 50% of the time, users will query all of the records where the other 50% of the time users will query the segmented smaller table data set. ( think based on all geographic areas vs. specific geographic areas)

Using a database managed by a shared hosting account ( think site5, godaddy, etc... ), is it faster to use a single larger table or to use several smaller segmented tables given this situation?

Where each dataset is accessed 10%/%90, 20%/%80, %30/%70... etc, at what point would using a single table vs muiltiple smaller tables be the most/least efficient?

Comment: I bet on single larger. 50% is already a lot.

Comment: So, your database desing has just this one table?

Comment: No of course not. Im talking specifically about this one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general do it so as to reduce the amount of duplicated information. If you are making smaller tables which have many redundant columns, then it seems like it'd be more efficient to have just one table. But otherwise, one table.

It also depends on what percent of the row is being used per query, and how your queries are structured. If you are adding lots of joins or subqueries, then it'll most likely be slower.

Comment: But using a shared hosting account arent there significant limitations on the ability of its hardware? Im wondering if performance will significantly be affected after reaching X number of records for a single table.

Comment: @dan-kanze shared hosting just shares all of the resources, to the best of my knowledge. While this is an interesting question you bring up, in theory queries which are more efficient given access to 100% of the CPU will still be the most efficient when you only have access to 10%. It is unlikely that they're going to hold the entire large table in memory, but on the other hand it doesn't seem likely that they'd let you hold multiple smaller tables in ram either- I honestly think that whatever works given full access to ram and CPU will scale down to the throttled ram/CPU too.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is the difference between two implimentations. On one side, we have a large table. 1/10th of this table will be accessed 50% of the time. While 100% of the table will be accessed the other 50% of the time. Think of the same usage with the second implimentation being 10 tables with a forgien key instead of 1 large table.

Comment: In the 10 table implementation, are you just using many joins? Or is it one query per table? What is your engine- myIsam or  innodb? How many queries per second?

Comment: Joins. MyISAM. Wont know for sure how many QPS exactly until it goes live.

Comment: @dan are you joining across all 10 of those tables then? If you have just one big table, would you be joining it on itself? Are you doing a lot of writes or just reads? If a lot of writes, is innodb an option?

Comment: All reads. Id only be joining on all of the tables some % of the time. My question is at what % will this be an effective implimentation. innodb not an option.

Comment: Without more details it's hard to give an exact answer, but it does seem that for you it would be more effecient to go with one table over many, to avoid the overhead of multiple tables being called. Setting tables to readonly if you can would boost things as well